# How to let CLR know which assembly to pick from GAC?

Tags: c#, .net, gac, .net-assembly

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Shapes;

namespace ShapeUser
{
    public class ShapeUser
    {
        public static void Main() 
        {
            Circle c = new Circle(1.0F);
            Console.WriteLine("Area of Circle(1.0) is {0}", c.Area());
            Console.ReadKey(); // press a key to exit program
        }
    }
}
```

This program is using `Shapes` assembly which is in the GAC. If there is only one assembly, its fine. But, the GAC may contain other assemblies with the same name (but different version and key).

**So, how to tell the CLR to load my assembly only not the others having same name?**

I'm confused. I know it is protected by public key encryption but still we should be having some private key in the program from where we are accessing it. Please clear my confusion.

Comment: When you reference Shapes in your project, you can specify to use a specific version.  If that specific version is unavailable, your program will fail to load.

Comment: @Torres! Suppose I've deployed my software somewhere else. Now I'm just updating the assembly version (to enhance it), I'd never want my application to be version specific. I think if we mention "1.0.*", it takes the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reference an assembly in the GAC you **must** reference it by its [strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx), a combination of its name, version number, culture (if provided) plus a public key and digital signature (assemblies must be signed to be considered strongly named, and only strongly named assemblies may be added to the GAC).

If you reference a strongly named assembly then you are already uniquely identifying what assembly you wish to use.  If you are referencing an assembly that isn't strongly named then that assembly can't be loaded into the GAC (and the .Net runtime won't check there anyway, see [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx)).

If you are referencing a strongly named assembly (or in fact *any* assembly) and want to accept multiple different versions of that assembly (e.g. v1.0.0.0 and v1.0.1.0), or you want to release a newer version of your assembly and allow existing applications to continue functioning without needing to be recompiled then you can use [Assembly Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to be able to reference an assembly regardless of what key is used to sign that assembly then you are best off not signing that assembly at all (and therefore not adding it to the GAC).

I believe that you can also [subscribe to the assembly resolve event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527268.aspx), however using assembly binding redirection is the preferred method, as long as it provides the desired behaviour.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I can use the same key (snk) to build the assembly again and again with different versions?

Comment: @Shashwat Yes, this is in fact exactly what you should be doing.  The snk is used to identify you (the company / supplier of the assembly), to prove that it is in fact you that has provided that assembly and that it hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: Ok got it. But one more doubt. If by chance, we lose that snk file; then is there any way to sign the assembly as before? Because 'sn -k Shape.snk' just creates a random key.

Comment: @Shashwat Nope, that key is precious - don't loose it!

Comment: Ohh! So, we are relying on a single key for our company name. I think there must be some ways to protect it. One of them can be creating multiple copies. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

When you compile, you can specify the exact version to use. That's the version that will be loaded at execution time. If you're using Visual Studio, the Properties for the reference will contain the version number, as well as a flag to say whether the exact version number has to be loaded or not.

Comment: But still (Name, Version) pair can also be duplicated.

Comment: @Shashwat: The assembly reference will *actually* also include the public key token, but I can't remember offhand whether that's visible in the project properties. That triple should be unique within the GAC, I believe.

Comment: But I'd never want to be too specific to refer to the assembly.
Suppose, I've deployed my application somewhere and it is using a particular assembly. Now, I'm enhancing only my assembly regularly thus changing the version. But I don't want to recompile my whole deployed application (where version is specified to load the assembly), then it won't load my assembly.

Comment: @Shashwat: Then you've got conflicting requirements - your question asks how to force the CLR to load a particular version, and now you're saying you *don't* want to force it to load a particular version. You need to decide whether you want that control or not.

Comment: I mean to say the CLR should not use the assembly created by someone else with the same name. It should be able to load my assemblies only with different version and key. Is is possible?

Comment: @Shashwat: I *believe* if you flip the flag to say it doesn't have to be that specific version, it will still check the public key. You should test it, of course.

Comment: Ok. So everytime we can have same assembly with different versions build with the same snk file.
I got it. But one more doubt. If by chance, we lose that snk file; then is there any way to sign the assembly as before? Because 'sn -k Shape.snk' just creates a random key.

Comment: @Shashwat: No, and you wouldn't want there to be. The whole point of signing the assembly is to *prove* that you've got the key. Store it somewhere safely.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly is defined by its name, public key token, and version. When you create a reference, you can be specific and indicate each of these values.

Comment: But suppose, I've deployed my application somewhere and it is using a particular assembly. Now, I'm enhancing only my assembly regularly thus changing the version. But I don't want to recompile my whole deployed application (where version is specified to load the assembly), then what to do?

Comment: You could do assembly binding redirects. You can tell your application, everywhere that references My.Library.dll version 0.0.0.0 - 2.3.4.5 should now point to version 2.4.0.0. This would be an application-wide redirect. It works as long as signatures haven't changed.